# Python: Rename row labels using a dictionary via map()-function?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a data frame for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
             'B':[10,20,30],       
             'C':[20,40,60]},
              index=["Row1","Row2","Row3"])
```

Now the task is to change the names of the index by using a map()-function and the following dictionary:

```
d = {"Row1":"FirstRow","Row2":"Secondrow","Row3":"Thirdrow"}
```

Can someone help? I could do it with a for loop but with the map-function I have no clue.

Comment: `df.rename(index=d)`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Index.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html) - if no match get `NaN`:

```
df.index = df.index.map(d)
```

Or if return same value if no match:

```
df.index = df.index.to_series().replace(d)
```

Alternative:

```
df = df.rename(d)
#explicit version, thanks Jon Clements
df = df.rename(index=d)
```

Comment: I'd probably be explicit and go for `df.rename(index=d)`... (doesn't make any difference but since the most common use of `.rename` is for columns - it just looks kinda like someone missed out `columns=` in it...)

Comment: Also - the documentation for `DataFrame.rename` says: "We *highly* recommend using keyword arguments to clarify your intent."